# How to create response video player | Video js | HLS videos

Tags: html, css, video, video.js

I've added a video player on my HTML page and using video js to support HLS videos as:

```
 <video id="video-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls>
        <source src="https://base_url/hls/18691/18691.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
 </video>
```

I want to make it responsive. I tried setting width, height to 100% but it's not working for me

Please note, I have other content as well in my HTML page (as shown in the screenshot).

***How to make this piece of code a responsive video player?***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the `vjs-fluid` class to the player.